# How to generate most recent nth day of the month?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, date

Simple question, but I haven't found any examples of this on Stack Exchange:

I need to be able to select all records in the current billing cycle, that's it. The catch is the billing cycle doesn't begin on the first of the month, so I can't just do `MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())`. I can compare the parts of the date individually, but handling wraparound for months and years is a pain. For example, if the billing cycle starts on the 15th of each month, then as of the date this is being posted, the date would be `2023-11-15`, not `2023-12-15`. And a month from now, it would be `2023-12-15`, a different month *and* year from the current date.

Because the SQL gets long and messy just handling this filter, I'd like to instead generate the start of the last billing date once and then compare the entire date against that directly, but I'm having some trouble putting that together. e.g. `WHERE date >= '2023-11-15'` (but generating this date dynamically). Subtracting `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` to get the month in which the billing cycle starts doesn't work, since that's only the case if it's before the day of the billing cycle in the current month. Is there an elegant way to compute the most recent `nth` day of the month in MySQL/MariaDB, whether that day is in the current month or the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest sticking this into a UDF to avoid cluttering up your SQL statement (especially if you want/need to parameterize which day of the month you're looking for) but it seems like the key bit is where you say "that's only the **case** if it's before the day ..." which led me directly to this:

```
select
    case when dayofmonth(current_date) <= 15 
        then date_add(
                date_sub(current_date, interval 1 month), 
                interval 15 - dayofmonth(current_date) day)                     
        else date_add(current_date, interval 15 - dayofmonth(current_date) day)
    end as LastFifteenth
```

Comment: I had to change `DAYS` to `DAY` to run this, but it seems to spit out `2023-12-15` for me, not `2023-11-15` - is that what you get?

Comment: With the caveat that I wrote it in DB2 SQL and then tried to translate to MYSQL for you, what I wrote produces `2023-11-15` for me.

Comment: Aha! It should be `DAYOFMONTH` not `DAY`. The basic logic looked right but I knew something was weird.